# Get computer name and/or full network file path

Tags: vbscript

Using `Scripting.FileSystemObject` I can get the full path name of a file, but this will always be like "c:\temp\myfile.txt". How can I get the name of the PC, or a network-path to the file like \MyPC\temp\myfile.txt? Is there another class other than `Scripting.FileSystemObject` I can use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Set wshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Network" )
strComputerName = wshNetwork.ComputerName
WScript.Echo "Computer Name: " & strComputerName
```

**Source:** http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_network_names_computer.php:

Comment: same command in one line WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName

Answer (score 1):

This is a single line answer that is equivalent to Chris's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244968/)

```
WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName
```